# RecyclerView not updating the view properly with ConstraintLayout Group Visibility

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**Problem:**

It seems when I have a specific combination of views and setVisibility between Visible and Gone the RecyclerView does not update properly after initial load.  I have a RelativeLayout->ConstraintLayout->Constraint Group(with visibility dynamically set).  The view within the constraint group is not updating properly.

**Example Use Case of Problem:**

So the linked code below it will show a search view at the top.  The initial state of empty shows the view properly(With the search icon showing).  Then if you type "T" then the search icon will disappear(it shouldn't).  So if you either delete the T or type the next letter "E" then it shows again.  Also if you delete all search text and type T again it will show.

**View Code:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.example.davidcorrado.myapplication.PlayerVM" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/playerCell_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp"


        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.constraint.Group
            android:id="@+id/playerCell_status_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{vm.showingStatusIcons}"

app:constraint_referenced_ids="playerCell_lineup_status_image" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playerCell_lineup_status_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**Quirks that might help:**

1) If I move the visibility line to the relativeLayout or the ConstraintLayout the things seem to work

2) If I remove the RelativeLayout view things seem to work.

See the below for the full code example:
https://github.com/DavidCorrado/LayoutIssue

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the reason the search icon disappears is due to the call to ObservableList.clear() then ObservableList.addAll(*)

So the disappear happens on the clear, then the reappear happens on the addAll. 
As the callbacks in the adapter kick in on both calls, my hunch is it animates the view to disappear, then animates to show when the addAll is triggered.

I have verified this by not actioning a 'List.clear()' and instead in your textChange listener simply adding more views to the list.

I'm not sure how you would clear and add items to the list without animating the clear, perhaps there are some settings you can toggle in the RecyclerAdapter to ignore the remove of Views or not animate the entry of Views?

My adjusted code in your callback for class PlayersListVM

```
class PlayersListVM {
    val filteredVms: ObservableList<ViewModel> = ObservableArrayList<ViewModel>()
    val showing = PlayerVM(isShowing = true)
    val missing = PlayerVM()

    init {
        filteredVms.add(showing)
    }

    fun onQueryChanged(newText: String) {
        if (filteredVms.size % 2 == 1) filteredVms.add(missing)
        else filteredVms.add(showing)
    }
}
```